# How to change <td> text on click in Vue 3?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a table displaying email data, including the email subject which is initially truncated (substr). I would like to display the full email subject when the table data cell is clicked.

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="email in emails.data" :key="email.id">
    <td v-text="store.getSubjectTruncated(email)" :title="store.getSubject(email)"></td>
    ...
```

Currently I've only been able to display the full subject as the "title" when hovering over the cell.

Is it possible to do something like @click="v-text = getSubject(email)"?

Comment: No you cant, you will need to change your v-text to handle this case with a boolean for example : `@click="displayFullEmail = true"` and `v-text=""displayFullEmail  ? store.getSubject(email) :  store.getSubjectTruncated(email)"`

Comment: @Lk77 thanks! this works great when I define const displayFullEmail =ref(false) in the script. Although this of course effects all rows rather than the single cell clicked. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: You can put the boolean somewhere on your object, like email.displayFullEmail, try if that works, there might be reactive issue though. If this does not work you can always store the id in an array instead

Answer (score 1):

In your script add a property called `currentShownEmail` :

```js
const currentShownEmail=ref(-1)
```

in template update that property with index value and use it render th email conditionally :

```html
  <tr v-for="(email,index) in emails.data" :key="email.id">
    <td @click="currentShownEmail=currentShownEmail===index?-1:index" 
            v-text=""currentShownEmail===index? store.getSubject(email) :  store.getSubjectTruncated(email)" 
            :title="store.getSubject(email)"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it simple, You can just invoke the required logic based on the flagged set on click the table cell.

Template **:**

```
<td @click="showFullSubject = true" v-text="showFullSubject ? store.getSubject(email) : store.getSubjectTruncated(email)"></td>
```

Script **:**

```
// Either in setup or onMounted, we can set showFullSubject default value as false.
onMounted() {
  showFullSubject: false;
}
```